# WHERE clause in sprintf()

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string that contains a number of email addresses that are coma separated i.e.

```
$emails = “111@abc.com, 222@abc.com, 333@abc.com”;
```

I have the bellow php code that work fine

```
<?php
function cust_get_oldest_items_all($limit = 1) {
    $mSearch = new Search();
    $result = $mSearch->dao->query(sprintf('SELECT pk_i_id FROM %st_item ORDER BY dt_pub_date LIMIT 0, %d', DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $limit ));

    return $result->result();
}
?>
```

I want to use WHERE clause in the php code above to include only those items whose s_contact_email is in $emails?

Comment: Using `sprintf` to compose queries is **extremely** risky and shouldn't be done. What is `dao` here? Can you use that to do the [escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate your emails this way:

```
$emails = "111@abc.com, 222@abc.com, 333@abc.com";
$emailsArr = explode(",",$emails);//make an array of emails    

//Todo: escape each array item (each email) to prevent SQL injection

//surround each email with single quotes
$emailsArr = array_map(function($e){return "'".trim($e)."'";},$emailsArr);

//join. new string looks like >> ('111@abc.com','222@abc.com','333@abc.com')
$emails = '('. implode(",",$emailsArr) .')';
```

And change your `SELECT` query to:

```
SELECT pk_i_id FROM %st_item 
WHERE s_contact_email IN $emails 
ORDER BY dt_pub_date LIMIT 0, %d
```

**security note**

This fix will work, but it's not enough. You must either properly escape each email address or use prepared statements to block attackers' attempts to take over your DB (SQL injection attack)

Comment: Thanks for your very useful reply, How can I use prepared statements? can you make code for me?

Comment: If my reply helped you solve your problem, please select my response as the right answer. As for prepared statements, I'm sorry I don't know how to help because it seems you're using a 3rd party tool to make your DB queries. It's a really big topic though so if you search prepared statement and the tool you're using, you're sure to find help.  Good luck.

Comment: Your reply helped me a lot, I have accepted and up voted your answer, please up vote my question if possible.